# Java Script Buffer,alloc(5,number.toString()) returns float

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, buffer

i was working with buffer in JavaScript. I want to write the buffer with first five digit of provided input. But instead of returning 23917 it return 2.391.Can someone explain why it does that?

Thank you so much in advance.

```
var number=23917397219379217392781;
var buffer=new Buffer.alloc(5,number.toString());
console.log(buffer.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because for large numbers, toString() returns a scientific-notation string representation of the number.

In your case, number.toString() is '2.3917397219379218e+22'.

To get around this, implement your own numberToString method, and use that to get a non-scientific-notation string like '23917397219379217392781'

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one more question why javascript does that and how to prevent it ?

Comment: Not sure *why* that's done. Many languages seem to do it. Maybe the reason can be found in the ECMAScript spec